# Ayuda con programa en c# y conversión de bases

Tags: c#

estoy en clase intentando hacer un programa que nos han puesto, y estoy encallado intentando hacer unas funciones que conviertan de cualquier base numérica a otra (de 1 a 16) y he hecho lo siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UF2PR2Solucio
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int opcio = 0;
            bool acabar = false;

            while (!acabar)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                opcio = menuPrincipal();
                switch (opcio)
                {
                    case 1:
                        decimalBinari();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        binariDecimal();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        decimalHexadecimal();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        HexadecimalDecimal();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        binariHexadecimal();
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        hexadecimalBinari();
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        qualsevol();
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        ajuda();
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        acabar = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("\nEsperava un numero de l'u al 9");
                        break;
                }
                if (!acabar) espera();
            }
        }
        public static void decimalBinari()
        {
            String numero;

            Console.WriteLine("Entra un numero decimal: ");
            numero = Console.ReadLine();
            //Comprovacio base
            if (esBase(10, numero)) Console.WriteLine(Conversio(10, 2, numero));
            else Console.WriteLine("Esperava un numero decimal");
        }
        public static void binariDecimal()
        {
            String numero;

            Console.WriteLine("Entra un numero binari: ");
            numero = Console.ReadLine();
            //Comprovacio base
            if (esBase(2, numero)) Console.WriteLine(Conversio(2, 10, numero));
            else Console.WriteLine("Esperava un numero binari");
        }
        public static void HexadecimalDecimal()
        {
            String numero;

            Console.WriteLine("Entra un numero hexadecimal: ");
            numero = Console.ReadLine();
            //Comprovacio base
            if (esBase(16, numero)) Console.WriteLine(convertirABaseDeu(16, numero));
            else Console.WriteLine("Esperava un numero hexadecimal");
        }
        public static void decimalHexadecimal()
        {
            String numero;

            Console.WriteLine("Entra un numero decimal: ");
            numero = Console.ReadLine();
            //Comprovacio base
            if (esBase(10, numero)) Console.WriteLine(Conversio(10, 16, numero));
            else Console.WriteLine("Esperava un numero decimal");
        }


        public static void binariHexadecimal()
        {
            String numero;

            Console.WriteLine("Entra un numero decimal: ");
            numero = Console.ReadLine();
            //Comprovacio base
            if (esBase(10, numero)) Console.WriteLine(Conversio(2, 16, numero));
            else Console.WriteLine("Esperava un numero binari");
        }


        public static void hexadecimalBinari()
        {
            String numero;

            Console.WriteLine("Entra un numero decimal: ");
            numero = Console.ReadLine();
            //Comprovacio base
            if (esBase(10, numero)) Console.WriteLine(Conversio(16, 2, numero));
            else Console.WriteLine("Esperava un numero hexadecimal");
        }


        public static void qualsevol()
        {//menu 7
            String numero;
            int baseInicial, baseDesti;

            Console.WriteLine("Entra un numero: ");
            numero = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Entra la base en que esta aquest nombre: ");
            baseInicial = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Entra la base a la que el vols convertir: ");
            baseDesti = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //Comprovacio base
            if (esBase(baseInicial, numero)) Console.WriteLine(convertirAbase(numero, baseInicial, baseDesti));
            else Console.WriteLine("El nombre introduit no és de la base especificada");
        }
        public static String Conversio(int baseInicial, int baseDesti, String Numero)
        {
            //String resultat;
            //int resultatB10;
            //Primer convertim de base inicial a base 10
            //resultatB10 = convertirABaseDeu(baseInicial, Numero);
            //Despres convertim de base 10 a base desti
            //resultat = convertirDeBaseDeu(resultatB10, baseDesti);
            //return "hola soc la funcio conversio";
            string valor;

            valor = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(Numero, baseInicial), baseDesti);

            return valor;

        }

        public static int convertirABaseDeu(int baseNum, String numero)
        {
            int resultat = 0;
            int llargada;
            int digit;
            int potencia = 0;

            llargada = numero.Length;
            for (int x = llargada - 1; x >= 0; x--)
            {
                digit = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(numero[x]);
                if (digit == -1) digit = Convert.ToInt32(numero[x]) - 55;

                resultat = resultat + (digit * Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(baseNum, potencia)));
                potencia++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("el valor a en decimal es : " + resultat);
            return resultat;
        }


        static void convertirAbase(string numero, int baseInicial, int baseDesti)
        {
            int quocient, residu, i = 0, base10 = convertirABaseDeu(baseInicial, numero.ToString());
            string conv = "";

            do
            {
                quocient = base10 / baseDesti;
                residu = base10 % baseDesti;
                conv.ToCharArray()[i] = (char)residu;
                numero = quocient.ToString();
                i++;
            } while (quocient > 0);

            Console.WriteLine("La conversio es: ");
            for (int cont = i - 1; cont >= 0; cont--)
            {
                Console.Write(conv[cont]);
            }
        }


        public static Boolean esBase(int laBase, String numero)
        {
            bool resultat = true;

            foreach (char digit in numero)
            {
                if (!digitPertanyBase(digit, laBase))
                {
                    resultat = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return resultat;
        }
        public static Boolean digitPertanyBase(char digit, int baseNum)
        {
            bool trobat = false;
            char[] simbols = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
            int x = 0;
            do
            {
                if (digit == simbols[x]) trobat = true;
                x++;
            }
            while ((x < baseNum) && (!trobat));
            return trobat;
        }

        public static int menuPrincipal()
        {
            int opcio = 0;
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki;

            escriureMenu();
            cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (Char.IsNumber(cki.KeyChar))
                opcio = Int32.Parse(cki.KeyChar.ToString());
            else opcio = 0;

            return opcio;
        }
        public static void escriureMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Conversió de bases numèriques");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - Decimal a binari");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - Binari a decimal");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - Decimal a hexadecimal");
            Console.WriteLine("4 - Hexadecimal a decimal");
            Console.WriteLine("5 - Binari a hexadecimal");
            Console.WriteLine("6 - Hexadecimal a binari");
            Console.WriteLine("7 - D'una base a qualsevol altra");
            Console.WriteLine("8 - Ajuda");
            Console.WriteLine("9 - Sortir");
        }
        public static void ajuda()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Si saps que són les bases numèriques, no et cal gaire ajuda");
            Console.WriteLine("Si tens alguna queixa, pots escriure-la i,quan premis ENTER serà enviada al nostres programadors");
        }



        public static void espera()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Prem ANY KEY per tornar al menu");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

El caso es que en la función convertirABase, al intentar llamarla en su correspondiente función, me dice que:

> no se puede convertir de void a bool

y no se por qué, alguna idea?

EDITO:

El principal problema reside en lo siguiente:

```
public static int convertirABaseDeu(int baseNum, String numero)
        {
            int resultat = 0;
            int llargada;
            int digit;
            int potencia = 0;

            llargada = numero.Length;
            for (int x = llargada - 1; x >= 0; x--)
            {
                digit = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(numero[x]);
                if (digit == -1) digit = Convert.ToInt32(numero[x]) - 55;

                resultat = resultat + (digit * Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(baseNum, potencia)));
                potencia++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("el valor a en decimal es : " + resultat);
            return resultat;
        }


        static void convertirAbase(string numero, int baseInicial, int baseDesti)
        {
            int quocient, residu, i = 0, base10 = convertirABaseDeu(baseInicial, numero.ToString());
            string conv = "";

            do
            {
                quocient = base10 / baseDesti;
                residu = base10 % baseDesti;
                conv.ToCharArray()[i] = (char)residu;
                numero = quocient.ToString();
                i++;
            } while (quocient > 0);

            Console.WriteLine("La conversio es: ");
            for (int cont = i - 1; cont >= 0; cont--)
            {
                Console.Write(conv[cont]);
            }
        }
```

Bien, como dije, estoy intentando crear una función que convierta de una base n a una base m, y he hecho esto, que no se si está muy bien (por eso me gustaría pedir algo de ayuda, a ver si alguien puede darme una orientación sobre cómo convertir las bases), el caso es que al llamar a la función convertirABase en el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
public static void qualsevol()
        {//menu 7
            String numero;
            int baseInicial, baseDesti;

            Console.WriteLine("Entra un numero: ");
            numero = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Entra la base en que esta aquest nombre: ");
            baseInicial = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Entra la base a la que el vols convertir: ");
            baseDesti = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //Comprovacio base
            if (esBase(baseInicial, numero)) Console.WriteLine(convertirAbase(numero, baseInicial, baseDesti));
            else Console.WriteLine("El nombre introduit no és de la base especificada");
        }
```

> Me dice que no se puede convertir de void a bool, y no entiendo el
>   porqué

... Alguien sabe a qué puede deberse?

Answer (score 1):

Tu función:

```
static void convertirAbase(string numero, int baseInicial, int baseDesti)
```

Es de tipo `void`, lo que quiere decir que no regresa ningún valor, y en esta línea:

```
Console.WriteLine(convertirAbase(numero, baseInicial, baseDesti));
```

...estás mandándola llamar de forma que `Console.WriteLine` espera un valor de retorno. La primera sugerencia del compilador es esperar un `bool`, después `char` y así sucesivamente para cada una de las sobrecargas. Por lo que tienes 2 opciones: o solo mandas llamar la función:

```
convertirAbase(numero, baseInicial, baseDesti)
```

ó haces que:

```
static void convertirAbase(string numero, int baseInicial, int baseDesti)
        {
            int quocient, residu, i = 0, base10 = convertirABaseDeu(baseInicial, numero.ToString());
            string conv = "";

            do
            {
                quocient = base10 / baseDesti;
                residu = base10 % baseDesti;
                conv.ToCharArray()[i] = (char)residu;
                numero = quocient.ToString();
                i++;
            } while (quocient > 0);

            Console.WriteLine("La conversio es: ");
            for (int cont = i - 1; cont >= 0; cont--)
            {
                Console.Write(conv[cont]);
            }
        }
```

retorne algún tipo de dato para que `Console.WriteLine` pueda mostrar algo en pantalla de consola.